# Adding css to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, plugins

I am creating a jQuery Gallery Plugin. The initial markup needed to make the plugin run is:

## HTML

```
<div class="riGallery">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="Description 1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-2.jpg" alt="Description 2"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-3.jpg" alt="Description 3"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Once the plugin is called, it is dynamically adding the rest of the HTML needed to make the plugin work.

## After added HTML

```
<div class="rigallery">
    <div class="ri-display">
        <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="Description 1"></a>
        <button class="ri-prev" href="http://example.com"><</button>
        <button class="ri-next">></button>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="Description 1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-2.jpg" alt="Description 2"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="img/gallery-img-3.jpg" alt="Description 3"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have all of the CSS in an external stylesheet, but once I create the new elements, they don't take on the styles in the stylesheet. The stylesheet is linked up to the HTML page that the plugin is on, and I am calling the plugin after the document loads...

## Plugin Call

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".riGallery").riGallery({
            thumbWidth: 100,
            thumbHeight: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

*How do I get the CSS from the stylesheet to load on the dynamically-created elements?*

Comment: CSS is applied to dynamically created elements.  Something else is causing your problem.  Do you have a jsFiddle you can show?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n9fvagbt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names are case sensitive, try renaming the class for your wrapping div to "rigallery".

Comment: I am now completely embarrassed. My classes in CSS were lowercase, which is why they weren't picking up the styles. How do I erase this forever?! :-) Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I would target specific classes that the plugin creates. You can see the classes that the plugin creates if you open the developer view in the browser. Then you can simply put the CSS in your external file with those classes that you are interested in. You may also need !important in your css since the plugin is likely redefining the CSS upon creation of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Styles will automatically applied to all dynamically created elements if you have the CSS selectors defined correctly.
But javascript event methods will not bind on dynamically created items. you have to bind them after creation of the elements.

Your problem may be some issues with js not css. Is it your js is applying the styles. If so you have to re-execute the js function after adding the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This will write the styles inline.

```
$("ul a > img").css("width", "100px").css("height", "100px");
```

or

This is better to set the img width and height. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

```
$("ul a > img").attr('width', '100').attr('height', '100');
```

Comment: Maybe add a class to the images <img class="someClass" src="img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="Description 1">  then fire this in your function. $(".someClass").css("width", "100px").css("Height", "100px");

Comment: I'd rather not add the CSS in with jQuery if at all possible.

Comment: In the CSS try.  div.rigallery ul li a > img {width:100px;height:100px;}

Comment: or ul li a > img {width:100px!important;height:100px!important;}